# Is it possible (in 2019) to appeal a Community♦ judgement? ("This question was deleted as spam or offensive")

Tags: discussion, spam, offensive, appeal

Earlier today I asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339551), seeking to clarify whether Stack Exchange (the commercial organisation) subscribes to a particular pseudo-scientific idea or not.

There ensued an animated, albeit entirely civil, discussion.

- Some people supported subscribing to the idea, regardless of SE's perspective
- Some people opposed subscribing to the idea, regardless of SE's perspective
- Some people speculated that SE probably subscribed to the idea
- Some people felt the question was ambiguous
- Many people thought the question worth downvoting
- Many other people thought the question worth upvoting

Certainly there was no unanimity, but there definitely was no shortage of intelligent exchange. Between humans.

Then Community♦ came along.

Community♦ deleted the question and said:

> This question was deleted as spam or offensive

I don't think the question was either spam or offensive.

I'm fairly certain that many others, whichever position above they took, also did not consider the question spam or offensive.

Is there any way to appeal a Community♦ judgement? Or is the judgement final?

Comment: So. Comments are not really a place for extremely extended discussion. Or for bringing back a question that was made to go away by the community by proxy.

Comment: No worries. Thank you for giving me back my afternoon. :D

Comment: The message has since been reworded to make it clear that Community isn't making the decision to delete, but that it was deleted in response to flags. It now says, "[This question] was flagged as spam or rude or abusive and deleted [x time ago] by Community."